# Cannot access CameraRoll - undefined is not an object(evaluating RCTCameraRollManager.getPhotos)

Tags: react-native

I cannot use 'CameraRoll' anymore. So as per some suggestions on StackOverFlow I downloaded RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj and added it under libraries. Then, I located libRCTCameraRoll.a under 'Products' and linked that under 'Build Phases'. And still nothing.

Am I doing something wrong? Just using CameraRoll component before used to do the trick but not anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import node_modules/react-native/Libraries/CameraRoll/RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj
Then Project Settings -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

Comment: Thanks, just to be more specific you have to Link Binary With Libraries in YourMainProject.xcodeproj not on RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj